# Generic interface and implementation - type cannot be converted

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

I have a generic interface defined as:

```
public interface ItemService<T extends Slicer, E extends ItemSlice> {
    E getItemHistory(final String id, final T slicer);
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class DynamoDbItemService implements ItemService<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbItemSlice> {
    public DynamoDbItemSlice getItemHistory(final String id, final DynamoDbSlicer slicer) {
    }
}
```

Here are the definitions of the four classes referenced above:

```
public interface Slicer {
    Map<String, ? extends Serializable> pointer();
}

public class DynamoDbSlicer implements Slicer {
    public Map<String, AttributeValue> pointer() {
    }
}

public interface ItemSlice extends Slice<Item> {
}

public interface Slice<T> {
    List<T> data();
    Slicer next();
}

public class DynamoDbItemSlice implements ItemSlice {
    publi ImmutableList<Item> data() {}
    public DynamoDbSlicer next() {}
}
```

I would like to reference the `ItemService` interface but for it to be bound to the `DynamoDbItemService` implementation so I can swap it out if necessary which I can do like so:

```
ItemService<? extends Slicer, ? extends ItemSlice> itemService = new DynamoDbItemService itemService();
```

but if I try to use `itemService` like this:

```
ItemSlice slice = itemService.getItemHistory(itemId, DynamoDbSlicer.first(1));
slice = itemService.getItemHistory(itemId, slice.next());
```

I get these two compilation errors:

```
Error:(231, 82) java: incompatible types: item.pagination.DynamoDbSlicer cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends pagination.Slicer

Error:(238, 62) java: incompatible types: pagination.Slicer cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? extends pagination.Slicer
```

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024056/java-extends-i-cannot-be-converted-to-extends-i) that `?` wildcards cannot be identical so my question is - can I do what I want - work with the interface? If so, how? Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

I have asked two previous questions related to this which have helped along the way ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365964/attempting-to-use-incompatible-return-type-with-class-implementing-serializabl) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369141/incompatible-type-generic-interface-and-implementation))

Comment: It would be nice if we could get all the relevant methods so we can debug this. You are missing quite a few methods in there, most notably `DynamoDbSlicer.first()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why the following wouldn't work for you:

```
ItemService<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbItemSlice> itemService = new DynamoDbItemService();
ItemSlice slice = itemService.getItemHistory("",  new DynamoDbSlicer());
```

But if you would like to make the code as modular as possible you can use this method to perform an unchecked cast *(pure evil some say)* and get the result you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ItemSlice slice = getMySlice(new DynamoDbItemService());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Slicer, E extends ItemSlice> E getMySlice(ItemService<T, E> service) {
    return service.getItemHistory("", (T) new DynamoDbSlicer());
}
```

And then of course there is the solution of passing the type inference responsibility to the actual field that is storing the value. I myself would go for this solution, as I think it offers the most flexibility:

```
public class DynamoDbItemService<T extends Slicer, E extends ItemSlice> implements ItemService<T, E>

ItemService<DynamoDbSlicer, DynamoDbItemSlice> itemService = new DynamoDbItemService();
ItemSlice slice = itemService.getItemHistory("", new DynamoDbSlicer());
```